# Laravel DB::update don't working, doing nothing at all, without any errors

Tags: sql, laravel

I am learning how to run raw SQL queries and stuck at UPDATE operation.

I have route for INSERT:

```
Route::get('/insert', function (){
    DB::insert('insert into posts (title, content) values (?, ?)', ['PHP with Laravel', 'Just testing']);
    return 'after insert';
});
```

And route for SELECT:

```
Route::get('/read', function (){
    $results = DB::select('select * from posts');
    return var_dump($results);
});
```

After SELECT query I see:

```
/home/pavel/www_mysite/TestLaravel/routes/web.php:31:
array (size=1)
0 => 
    object(stdClass)[239]
      public 'id' => int 11
      public 'title' => string 'PHP with Laravel' (length=16)
      public 'content' => string 'Just testing' (length=12)
      public 'created_at' => null
      public 'updated_at' => null
      public 'is_admin' => int 0
```

And at least UPDATE query:

```
Route::get('/update', function (){
    DB::update('update posts set title = "Nothing here"');
});
```

After that query the new SELECT query shows the same data and in PHPPgAdmin I found no changes. I installed LaravelDebugBar and may see it at the bottom of the browser at pages for INSERT and SELECT queries, but don't see it at the page for UPDATE query. I cannot realize, where is the mistake.

Comment: I get it working after changing double quotes with escaped single quotes like this:
    `Route::get('/update', function (){
        DB::update('update posts set title = \'Nothing here\'');
    });`

But why the query don't working with double quotes?

Comment: I installed MySQL and try the same queries and they just works. INSERT into MySQL database works with double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extra research I found that PostrgreSQL may store case-sensitive names of tables and columns. For that case you need to take their names in double quotes in your query. I think that when PostrgreSQL found double quotes in the query - it "thinks" that it is table/column name. But there is no column with those name.

Answer (score 0):

try to use where clause.
example :

```
$affected = DB::update('update users set votes = 100 where name = ?', ['John']);
```

Comment: But "where" will just filter records, not rid the problem. Please look at my update in comment under question itself. Have you any idea regard it?

Answer (score 0):

I tested you code too and it work
[see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVFnM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I run your update code on my local environment (laravel 5.2, mysql 5.1). It's updated OK.

How about your log?